# Prove that there exists r > 0 such that Df(x) is surjective.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

The question is:

Suppose that the derivative $Df(c)$ is a surjective linear transformation. Prove that there exists $r>0$ such that $Df(x)$ is surjective for all $ x \in B_{r}(c)$.

Could anyone give me a hint for the solution please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true if you just assume $f$ is differentiable in a neighbourhood of $c$.  For example, in one dimension, $$f(x) = \cases{x + x^2 \sin(1/x^2) & if $x \ne 0$\cr
0 & if $x=0$}$$ is differentiable in $(-1,1)$, with  $f'(0)=1$, but $f'(x)$ takes all real values (including $0$) in any neighbourhood of $0$.

Comment: You mean the question is wrong ?

Comment: If the question is exactly what you wrote, then  it is wrong.

Comment: So why in your example the derivative is a surjective linear transformation?

Comment: I see that your c is 0 .... am I correct? and I see that you are not agreeing on the statement "there exist r > 0" am I correct? also how your example say that $Df(x)$ is not surjective for all $x \in B_{r}(c)$ ..... could you please explain this for me?

Comment: I see that you are not agreeing on the statement "there exist r" and you want it "for all r" correct?

Comment: $f'(0) = 1$ so $Df(0)$ is the linear transformation $t \to t$, which is surjective.  There is no $r > 0$ such that $Df(x)$ is surjective for all $x \in B_r(0)$, because  $B_r(0)$ contains points $x$ where $f'(x) = 0$ (and thus $Df(x) = 0$).

Answer (score 2):

**If** $f$  is $C^1$, $Df$ is continuous. $Df(c)$ surjective  $\implies$ some minor of $Df(c)$ $\ne 0$  $\implies\cdots$

Comment: Why Df is continuous?

Comment: @Intuition **IF** is continuous (additional hypothesis required)

Comment: I did not understand your comment.

Comment: @Intuition, see the other answer. Supposing $Df$ continuous is required. Edit your question.

Comment: I know that if f in $C^{1}$ then it has continuous partial derivatives and so by a theorem f is differentiable and hence f is continuous, does not the continuity of $f$ implies the continuity of the partial derivative?

Comment: @hopefully, utterly *false* as written. But is true that the continuity of ${\bf f'}$ implies the continuity of the partial derivatives.