# Correcting a question so that it becomes true.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, analysis, multivariable-calculus

The question is given here in the following link:

[Prove that there exists r > 0 such that Df(x) is surjective.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3170876/prove-that-there-exists-r-0-such-that-dfx-is-surjective)

But I am wondering if I change the statement from "there exist r" to "for all r" will the statement be correct?

Also what does "**Df(c)** is surjective linear transformation" in the statement of the question mean in the 1-dimensional case?

Comment: Am I misunderstanding - if you can't prove it true for a single $r$, how can you prove it for all $r$? And for functions $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, the linear map $df(x) : \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is surjective iff it is invertible (i.e. not zero)

Comment: If you read the correction in the link (and the counter example given their and my comments on the counterexample ) I think you may understand what I mean ...... please read them and tell me your suggestions @CalvinKhor

Comment: What about the condition of being 1-1 on $df(x)$ is it satisfied? @CalvinKhor

Comment: I have read it and I don't understand what you're confused about. Can you try to write down exactly the statement you think might be true? A linear map $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is surjective iff injective.

Comment: This is the statement I think it is true "Suppose that the derivative $Df(c)$ is a surjective linear transformation. Prove that for all $r>0$  $Df(x)$ is surjective for all $ x \in B_{r}(c)$." @CalvinKhor

Comment: OK - then see my first comment.

Comment: Actually I can not see the problem in the question in the link that the counterexample pointed out ..... I need an explanation for the counterexample... this is what I am asking .... could you explain it for me and how it contradict the question given? @CalvinKhor

Comment: I have read your comment but I understood that the counterexaple say that it is correct for all r ..... is my understanding for the counterexample correct?@CalvinKhor

Comment: It is like the linked counterexample proves that $f(n)$ is not divisible by 3, and now you are asking if $f(n)$ is divisible by 9. Suppose you could prove the "for all $r$" version is true. In particular then, it is true for $r=1$ and therefore there exists an $r$ where it is true, in contradiction with the linked counterexample

Comment: No, the counterexample shows that it is not true for any $r$, i.e. there does not exist an $r$ so that the statement is true

Comment: So I do not understand the counterexaple ..... How it opposes the question given ?@CalvinKhor

Comment: why there does not exist an r?@CalvinKhor  what is the part of the counterexample that say this?

Comment: the part that says there are stationary points arbitrarily close to $c=0$

Comment: Stationary points means fixed points ? or isolated points?@CalvinKhor

Comment: No, a stationary point is a point where the tangent line is horizontal

Comment: where is this part exactly in the counterexample ?@CalvinKhor

Comment: "but $f'(x)$ takes all real values (including $0$) in any neighbourhood of $0$."

Comment: So the example is saying that there is no r for which $Df(x)$ is surjective for all x in an r nbhd of c ..... correct?@CalvinKhor

Comment: the answer is indeed a counterexample to the linked question

Comment: So the problem is that the nbhd contains the c , which is equal to zero .... correct@CalvinKhor

Comment: It seems you understand, so I dont think you need to ask me that?

Comment: yes thank you so much for your patience and kindness ..... could you please help me in removing  my doubts in this question also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3170545/prove-or-disprove-the-hilbert-schmidt-norm-is-independent-of-the-choice-of-basi @CalvinKhor

Comment: You're welcome, but I can't do that at this time. Good luck